# Find the higher number between two cells and divide by two

Tags: excel, excel-formula, max, formula, min

In Excel, I have two cells side by side and I know the cell on the right (D4) has a higher value than the cell on the left (C4).

So I subtract cell on the right (D4) by the cell on the left (C4). And I need to divide the result by 2, so I use:

```
=(D4-C4)/2
```

However, sometimes, it can happen that the cell C4 is higher than the D4, and I have no idea of what formula to use to first find witch cell should I divide by the other.

I tried like this:

```
=(MAX(C4;D4) - MIN(C4;D4)) / 2
```

However this does not work.

Comment: Consider  `=(MAX(C4:D4) - MIN(C4:D4)) / 2`  or your language-equivalent for `MAX()` and `MIN()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider:

```
=ABS(D4-C4)/2
```

[image]

You don't need to know which value is greater.